# Tab delimited txt file PHP selecting from array

Tags: php

I am trying to select columns in my tab separated document. 
The problem i am having is i get this error....

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 11 
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 12 
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 13

Code:

```
$file = "t_rac.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); // Make all conditions to avoid errors
$read = file_get_contents($file); //read
$lines = explode("\n", $read);//get
$i= 0;//initialize
$o=1;
foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    $cols[$i] = explode("\t", $value);

    $list=($cols[$o++][1]);
    $list.=($cols[$o++][6]);
    $list.=($cols[$o++][7]);

$i++;
}
echo $list;
```

Comment: show a sample of your data, its hard to picture it!

Comment: Try changing your $o++ to $i

Comment: Sample data would be nice

Comment: [Here i  a screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B18p7MRACKchQUlwX3Y5MU9Mb00/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code off of data this works for ya.

I skip the 1st line, and make sure the column is not out of bounds before adding item.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $read); //get
$i = 0;//initialize
$list = "";
foreach($lines as $value)
{ 
  if($i != 0)
  {
     $cols[$i] = explode("\t", $value);

     if(isset($cols[$i][1]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][1]);

     if(isset($cols[$i][6]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][6]);

     if(isset($cols[$i][7]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][7]);

     $list.= "<br />";
   }

   $i++;
}
echo $list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array keys are totally wrong:

```
$list=($cols[$o++][1]);
             ^^^^
```

That changes `$o` every time you use it. So on your first iteration of the loop, you're doing:

```
$list=($cols[1][1]);
$list.=($cols[2][6]);
$list.=($cols[3][7]);
```

Note that `$o` is now 4... On your second iteration you're doing

```
$list=($cols[4][1]);
$list.=($cols[5][6]);
$list.=($cols[6][7]);
```

and `$o` is `7` at the end of the iteration, etc... If you have 100 rows to process, `$o` will end up being `301`, and you do **NOT** have that many columns in your `$cols` array.

Comment: I dont quite under stand. $list=($cols[1][1]);
`
$list.=($cols[2][6]);
$list.=($cols[3][7]);
$list=($cols[4][1]);
$list.=($cols[5][6]);
$list.=($cols[6][7]); 
`
Is what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using the **fgetcsv** PHP function to parse character delimited files.  There is no need to use explode.

**Edit** - I just read your other comment and understand now what you mean.  Updated.

**Edit** - So you need to get columns 1, 6 and 7 from the same row then.  Also added check for first row.

```
function getMeTheString($file) {
    $str = "";
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) === FALSE) return;
    $line = 0;
    while (($cols = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($line > 0) { // Ignore 1st line
            $str .= $cols[1];
            $str .= $cols[6];
            $str .= $cols[7];
        }
        $line++;
    }
    return $str;
}
echo getMeTheString("t_rac.txt");
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but im getting these errors....   

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 7

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like perhaps not all of your rows have 8 columns?  Can you show the start of your data file?

Comment: i got it working kinda. [here is what i got] (http://www.codeshare.io/jQo2h) the only error im getting now is 


Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in E:\xampp\htdocs\qrcode\tab.php on line 14

i only get this error one time and thats at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much everyone! Here is the working code! Works like a charm @Demodave Thank you!!

```
<?php
$file = "t_rac.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); // Make all conditions to avoid errors
$read = file_get_contents($file); //read
$lines = explode("\n", $read); //get
$i = 0;//initialize
$list = "";
foreach($lines as $value)
{ 
  if($i != 0)
  {
     $cols[$i] = explode("\t", $value);

     if(isset($cols[$i][2]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][2]);
$list.= "--";

     if(isset($cols[$i][3]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][3]);
$list.= "--";

     if(isset($cols[$i][4]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][4]);
$list.= "--";


     if(isset($cols[$i][6]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][6]);
$list.= "--";

      if(isset($cols[$i][7]))
        $list.=($cols[$i][7]);
$list.= "--";

     if(isset($cols[$i][23]))
      $list.=($cols[$i][23]);

     $list.= "<br />";
   }

   $i++;
}
echo $list;
?>
```